# Writing an IF EXISTS Query in an Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to be able to have a simple way to check if a query returns anything as an attempt to see if a record exists before I enter it.

So in MS-SQL I would do the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN = 'THISVALUE')
BEGIN
//Insert field
END
```

Easy.

This doesn't work in Oracle and the best alternative I have found is more verbose:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TEMPVAR
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYCOLUMN = ‘THISVALUE’

IF TEMPVAR = 0
BEGIN
//Insert field
END
```

So I want to put this into a function so I can do:

```
IF myPackage.Exists(SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN = 'THISVALUE')
BEGIN
//Insert field
END
```

But here is where I am stuck. How do I execute a query within a case statement when the query has to be generic? I am using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but no luck.

```
CASE
WHEN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS MYVAR
```

(and then returning that var).

Comment: Thanks Damien.  I added an example along the lines of `myPackage.exists` in your post that takes an input of a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query, but I realize that this may not be sufficient if it a requirement that the exists function accept `SELECT *` type  query strings instead.  Can you work with `SELECT COUNT(*)` as an input or is `SELECT *` required?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INTO` a variable and use that in conditional statements.

An example is below that makes a function whose input is a `SELECT COUNT(*)` type query string and whose output is `TRUE` if the count is > 0.

First create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(X NUMBER);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1);
```

Then create the package:

```
CREATE PACKAGE MYPACKAGE AS
  FUNCTION DOES_IT_EXIST(QUERY_STRING IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN;
  END MYPACKAGE;
  /

CREATE PACKAGE BODY MYPACKAGE AS
  FUNCTION DOES_IT_EXIST(QUERY_STRING IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    V_ITEM_COUNT NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY_STRING INTO V_ITEM_COUNT;
      RETURN (V_ITEM_COUNT > 0);
      END;

END MYPACKAGE;
/
```

Then test it:

```
BEGIN
  IF (MYPACKAGE.DOES_IT_EXIST('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE X = 1'))
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1 EXISTS');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1 does not exist');
  END IF;

  CASE WHEN (MYPACKAGE.DOES_IT_EXIST('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE X = 99'))
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('99 EXISTS');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('99 does not exist');
  END CASE;

END;
/

1 EXISTS
99 does not exist
```

Comment: Thanks! That's looks like what I needed. I may try and get it to work with SELECT * but SELECT COUNT(*) is very workable too!

Comment: in execute immediate you can wrap user query into `'select count(*) from ('||query_string||')'`, then all user queries would be supported

Comment: Thanks @vav That could provide a clean adapter for `SELECT *`

Comment: Thanks @Damien vav's comment seems like a succinct adapter between `SELECT *` and `SELECT COUNT(*)` if needed.

Comment: Yup! Thanks @vav and @alexgibbs!